# How is the recursion implemented in preorder traversal?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

i am not understanding the recursion in pre order traversal

```
  void preorder(node*root)

    { 
      if(root==NULL) return;
      printf("%c",root->data);
      preorder(root->left);
      preorder(root->right);
    }
```

following is the iteration :

preorder(200)--> preorder(150)--> preorder(400)--> preorder(250)--> preorder(0)
    i.e preorder(root->left) which is NULL, it returns to next instruction--> preorder(0)
    i.e preorder(root->right) which is NULL,it returns

now my question is why does not the traversal end after this step i am not understanding the recursion can someone explain the step by step iteration after this step recursion seems very simple but in implementation it is very complicated.

```
                 ROOT[200]
          200 F
           / \
          /   \
     150 C    350 D
      / \        / \
     /   \      /   \
400 E  450 F   60 G  700 H
   / \          \
  /   \          \
 250 A  180 B     600  K
```

Comment: What is your question, again? How recursion works?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: How is this not clear? It is quite clear to me and the answer seems to address the question. Perhaps the predicate should not be “implement”, rather “work”, as in, how does recursion work ...(in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will simplify it for you, given the code and tree you mentioned above.

```
    void preorder(node*root)
    { 
      if(root==NULL) return;
      printf("%c",root->data);
      preorder(root->left);
      preorder(root->right);
    }



         ROOT[200]
          200 F
           / \
          /   \
     150 C    350 D
      / \        / \
     /   \      /   \
400 E  450 F   60 G  700 H
   / \          \
  /   \          \
 250 A  180 B     600  K
```

Iteration goes like this:

```
preorder(200)
preorder(200->Left) i.e. preorder(150) ---preorder(200->Right)--Pending In Stack-
preorder(150->Left) i.e. preorder(400) ---preorder(150->Right)--Pending In Stack-
preorder(400->Left) i.e. preorder(250) ---preorder(400->Right)--Pending In Stack-
preorder(250->Left) i.e. preorder(NULL)---preorder(250->Right)--Pending In Stack-
```

After NULL is passed it would return. And the next element pending in stack would be executed.

```
// In our case the function being called was
preorder(250)
{
  preorder(250->Left);  // It returned.
  preorder(250->Right); // Next Statement Pending in Stack.
}
```

Below are the statements pending in the stacks:

> preorder(200->Right)--Pending In Stack-
>
> preorder(150->Right)--Pending In Stack-
>
> preorder(400->Right)--Pending In Stack-
>
> preorder(250->Right)--Pending In Stack-

Following the order. Next Statement out of the stack would be:

```
preorder(250->Right) i.e. preorder(NULL)--preorder(400->Right)--Pending In Stack-
```

preorder(400->Right) is part of the function:

```
preorder(400)
{
  preorder(400->Left);  // 250
  preorder(400->Right);
}
```

Now since 400->Left i.e. 250 had done both -> (250->Left) and (250->Right). It would return the control back to (400->Right)

> Similarly the recursion would keep on going until the entire tree is traversed. I know its hard to understand in the beginning but don't loose the spirit. Start from the basic recursions and try to come up with solutions on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement ends the execution of the current function and returns control to the calling function; the execution continues *right at the **next** point following the call*. It won't automagically end up the execution of the calling function.